# conditionally testing for equality of vector's elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

Although it seems pretty simple, I'm not sure of the most efficient way of doing this.

I have two vectors:

```
std::vector<bool> a;
std::vector<int> b;
```

`a.size()` necessarily equals `b.size()`.

each bool in `a` corresponds to an int in `b`. I want to create a function:

```
bool test(std::vector<bool> a, std::vector<int> b);
```

This function returns `true` if the values in `a` are equal. However, it only considers values in `a` that correspond to `true` values in `b`.

I could do this:

```
bool test(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<bool> b){
    int x;
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i){
        if(b.at(i) == true){
            x = a.at(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i){
        if(b.at(i) == true){
            if(a.at(i) != x){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But then I have to create two loops. Although the first loop will stop at the first true value, is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks good enough to me:

- Each loop does a different thing anyway (so you shouldn't worry about duplication)
- You don't use extranious variables or flags that complicate the code.

The only problems I see are:

- You start the second loop at 0 instead of where you left off.
- Doing `if(condition == true)` is very ugly. Just do `if(condition)` instead.

---

```
bool test(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<bool> b){
    int x;
    unsigned i;
    for(i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        if(b.at(i)){
            x = a.at(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i++; i < a.size(); i++){
        if(b.at(i)){
            if(a.at(i) != x){
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one loop if you remember if you have seen the first `true` element in `b` or not. Also, you should take the `a` and `b` parameters by reference to avoid unnecessary copying. And finally, if you know that the indices into a vector are always within valid range (i.e. between 0 and vector.size() - 1, inclusive), you can use `operator[]` instead of `at`, and achieve better peformance (`at` does a range check, while `operator[]` does not). Heres a modified version of your `test` function considering all the above points:

```
bool test(std::vector<int> const& a, std::vector<bool> const& b){
    int x;
    bool first = true;
    for(unsigned i = 0, n = a.size(); i != n; ++i){
        if( b[i] ){
            if( first ) {
                x = a[i];
                first = false;
            }
            else if( x != a[i] ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I am not a big fan of control-flow boolean variables. It looks like you are doing this "in one loop" just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you know a.size() == b.size() just create a single loop that compares an 'a' element to a 'b' element at the same time at each iteration.  Once you see that a[i] != b[i] then you know the containers don't match and you can break out.

Comment: I believe that is not what he wants to do

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain I know what you want to do but a straight compare once you know you have equal size

```
std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::equal_to<bool>())
```